# Package de interface grafica

Tags: python, gui, aplicação-desktop

Eu estou querendo iniciar um projeto bem grande pra começar a aprender melhor Python e alguns outros conceitos, tenho conhecimento básico sobre a linguagem, já fiz alguns scripts, principalmente complementos para o software [Blender](https://blender.org).

Mas agora quero criar uma aplicação bem mais complexa, com interface gráfica e tudo mais.
A ideia era um criar simulador de evolução de IA onde um algoritmo genético seleciona "Criaturas" aleatórias em um ambiente simulado com uma física muito simples.

As criaturas consistiram em pontos no espaço que aplicam forças uns sobre os outros, não colidem em nada e são controlados por uma pequena rede neural.

O ponto é que vou precisar de um package de interface gráfica, todos os que eu encontrei são difíceis de instalar no windows e o tkinter me parece mal documentado pra iniciantes.

e gostaria de poder compilar o app no final mas teria o problema com depentencias aos packages que o usuário teria que instalar na maquina.

Queria saber de uma solução de interface gráfica que desse suporte a renderização na interface e que fosse "portátil".
 com portátil me refiro a algo como:  `from pasta_do_lado import package`

Comment: Isto é uma maneira: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html

Comment: Pygame talvez? Funciona sobre a SDL, fiz um sistema gravitacional com essa biblioteca